# SQL query - Which TYPE of JOIN is required for my query?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two sql queries

1st Query : I am getting all details except the date related details

```
SELECT  att.roll_no  AS `att_roll_no`,att.full_name,att.st_class,att.st_section,
SUM(att.hasAttended= 'P') AS DaysPresent, 
SUM(att.hasAttended= 'A') AS DaysAbsent, 
COUNT(DISTINCT att.att_date) AS WorkingDays,
COUNT(*) AS totalClasses
FROM     attendance as att
WHERE att.st_class = 1 AND att.st_section = 'A' 
GROUP BY att.roll_no
```

The output table for above query is as follows :

[image]

2nd Query : I am getting only date related details

```
SELECT  hasAttended, att_date  FROM attendance
WHERE st_class = 1 AND st_section = 'A' AND att_date = 'Tue Apr 02 2013'
GROUP BY roll_no
```

The output table for above query is as follows :

[image]

Now I need to join the above two tables to one table.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

In the resultant query I am using INNER JOIN. Its as follows :

```
SELECT
  att_outer.hasAttended,
  att_outer.att_date
FROM
  attendance AS att_outer
  INNER JOIN(
    SELECT 
      att.roll_no  AS `att_roll_no`,
      att.full_name,
      att.st_class,att.st_section,
      SUM(att.hasAttended= 'P') AS DaysPresent, 
      SUM(att.hasAttended= 'A') AS DaysAbsent, 
      COUNT(DISTINCT att.att_date) AS WorkingDays,
      COUNT(*) AS totalClasses
    FROM 
      attendance as att
    WHERE
      att.st_class = 1
      AND att.st_section = 'A' 
    GROUP BY att.roll_no
  )att ON att_outer.roll_no = att.roll_no
WHERE 
  att_outer.st_class = 1
  AND att_outer.st_section = 'A'
  AND att_outer.att_date = 'Tue Apr 02 2013'
GROUP BY roll_no
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'att.roll_no' in 'on clause'
```

**Please let me know whether the resultant query is correct or not. Also join I am using is correct or not.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have supplied an alias of that column in your inner query. You should use that alias because that column is not visible anymore.

```
SELECT  att_outer.hasAttended, 
        att_outer.att_date,
        att.full_name,
        att.st_class,
        att.st_section,
        att.DaysPresent,
        att.DaysAbsent,
        att.WorkingDays,
        att.totalClasses
FROM    attendance AS att_outer
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  att.roll_no  AS `att_roll_no`,
                    att.full_name,
                    att.st_class,
                    att.st_section,
                    SUM(att.hasAttended= 'P') AS DaysPresent, 
                    SUM(att.hasAttended= 'A') AS DaysAbsent, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT att.att_date) AS WorkingDays,
                    COUNT(*) AS totalClasses
            FROM    attendance as att
            WHERE   att.st_class = 1 AND 
                    att.st_section = 'A' 
            GROUP   BY att.roll_no
        )att ON att_outer.roll_no = att.att_roll_no
WHERE   att_outer.st_class = 1 AND 
        att_outer.st_section = 'A' AND 
        att_outer.att_date = 'Tue Apr 02 2013'
```

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing out that but in my resultant table I am getting only the rows of my outer table.. I need the rows of my inner table as well...

Comment: see my updated answer. you have not projected it. also remove the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You want to join on the ALIAS name instead, the alias being `att_roll_no`

change:

```
 ON att_outer.roll_no = att.roll_no
```

To

```
ON att_outer.roll_no = att_roll_no
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks I corrected that.. But now in my resultant table I am getting only the rows of my outer table.i.e. only two rows - att_outer.hasAttended, att_outer.att_date.. I need all the rows of my inner table as well...

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a column called roll_no in the select clause, therefore you cannot do a join on this and thus the error: att.roll_no.